# Can Java Lambda expressions be used in JSP scriptlets?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, lambda, scriptlet

I have the following Java code I need to execute in a JSP source file. I first create a `Map` object:

```
Map<String,String> data = new HashMap<>(6);
data.put("Java version", "java.version");
data.put("Java home directory", "java.home");
// and so on until it's full
```

After the `Map` instance is filled with data I attempt to retrieve and display said data by using the following lambda expression:

```
final JspWriter out2 = out;
data.forEach((m,n) ->
{
    try
    {
        out2.println(m + ", " + n + "<br />");
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {}
});
```

I get 2 exceptions from the two blocks of code above. The first error is from the first block, when I declare the `Map` instance:

```
PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 27 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
```

I can easily fix this by rewriting the first line of the first block by replacing the diamond operator with its full form like this:

```
Map<String,String> data = new HashMap<String,String>(6);
```

For the second block, the reported error message is:

```
PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 27 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
```

Now, I could solve this error by simply rewriting that block of Java code, replacing it with something that does the same task but without utilizing lambda expressions. But this would be a workaround and I'd much rather use Java8 features. Based on the error messages I am receiving, it seems to me that somewhere along the compiling process, Java is mistakenly using JDK 1.5 instead of 1.8. Maybe one of the GlassFish libraries was written using JDK 1.5 and so is forcing my whole code to comply with that JDK version? I'm really out of ideas of what to do to make my Java8 code compile.

My currently installed JDK is version 1.8.0_77. I'm using NetBeans 8.1 to develop all of this, in conjunction with GlassFish Server 4.1.1. In NetBeans I made sure to check that ProjectProperties=>Sources=>Source/BinaryFormat is set to JDK8 for this project.

**Note:** Both error messages were preceded by the following lines, which I edited out to make things more readable:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release

PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
```

And here is the full GlassFish server log:

```
Severe:   Error compiling file: C:\Users\Server\GlassFish_Server\glassfish\domains\myLocalDomain1\generated\jsp\hwk5\org\apache\jsp\index_jsp.java
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: PWC6033: Error in Javac compilation for JSP
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
source value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
To suppress warnings about obsolete options, use -Xlint:-options.
PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 27 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
diamond operator is not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 7 or higher to enable diamond operator)
PWC6197: An error occurred at line: 27 in the jsp file: /index.jsp
PWC6199: Generated servlet error:
lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.5
  (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:129)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:299)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateClass(Compiler.java:392)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:453)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:625)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:375)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I think, you should look at your project properties. It seems, you entered "JDK 5" in "sources ->  source/binary format" (netbeans)

Comment: @Holger Hi. I Already tried that and it's using JDK8. I also opened the `project.properties` file and I made sure it contained `javac.source=1.8` and `javac.target=1.8`. So I'm thinking the problem lies on the GlassFish Server libraries instead of my project, but I'm not sure how to change the lowest JDK that these files use, nor if it's even possible to do so. I'd imagine I would maybe have to open up their jar files and hunt down some setting in particular but I'm not sure what or where.

Comment: try to google `target value 1.5 is obsolete and will be removed in a future release`
The ant compiler seems to have an own properties file. The Manifest may take a `minSdkVersion`